Using OCL to initialize variables for simulation with MagicDraw
I have an activity diagram and want to simulate it using the Cameo Simulation Toolkit.
After simulating the activity I want to check whether or not some specific actions have been used (that mean, which scenario or path of the activity diagram has been used).
After checking which scenario has been performed I want to get a message that tells me whether or not the test passed or failed. For this reason I set the "testcase" stereotype as an applied stereotype to the activity.
To initialize the variables I am trying to use OCL2.0 setting a constraint with e.g. this command and then I trigger the simulation:
context Test::myVariable: Integer init 1

Unfortunately, this initialization seems to be ignored when I use OCL but it seems to work when I use python as the language for the constraint.
Am I doing something wrong here or is OCL not supported to initialize variables/parameters?

Of course it should work. I understand that MagicDraw uses Eclipse OCL although they have never asked for permission/advice or offered any support.
Using the Eclipse OCL editor for RoyalAndLoyal.ocl the following parses ok.
context LoyaltyAccount::points : Integer init : 0

But if the final : is removed to imitate your example, the editor reports "mismatched input ':' expecting '('"
It would appear that your example has a typo, or else you are not using an adequate OCL or that your OCL is not adequately embedded within MagicDraw.
Try adding the missing ':' and if that works find out how to use the Eclipse Complete OCL editor within MagicDraw so that you get better diagnosis.
